# AngularJS, $window.open(URL, "_blank") Why when to the same function are passed different URLs some of them are closed by Ad Blocker some of them not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, window.open, adblock

maybe I am asking an easy question to the some of you but I am still new to AngularJS and I am a bit stuck with the following problem: I am trying to redirect a user when he hit a button to affiliate website and the function which is doing that job it used to work fine until soon when the ad Blocker started closing some of the sites to which I am trying to redirect the users but NOT to each of them. For example:

```
`$scope.copyToBookie = function () {

 var win = $window;



win.open(URL, "_blank");

  }`

// If URL = "https://dspk.kindredplc.com/redirect.aspx?pid=6949364&bid=27283&unibetTarget=/betting#home?coupon=combination|2396805806,2396805806|0|replace" Ad Blocker Close it

// If URL = "https://www.bet365.dk/instantbet/default.asp?bs=1552488438~1/2&Instantbet=1&s#/HO/" Ad Blocker Does NOT Close it("It is working fine")
```

Please help

Comment: I'd want my ad blocker to block both tbh.

Comment: Probably the adblock addon has one of the URLs on its blacklist, or it matches the ad pattern it's looking for. This seems a bit off-topic since it's not directly a programming issue.

Comment: Don't think this is angularjs related at all

Comment: @CBroe could you explain why?